# Изменение текста в ComboBox при выборе диапазона с DateTimePicker

Tags: база-данных, delphi, firebird

У меня есть БД с работниками направленными в командировку. Как реализовать, чтобы в `ComboBox` ФИО определенных работников загружалось после того как я выберу диапазон дат, а ФИО работников не попавших в диапазон - игнорировалось?

Comment: А в чем именно у вас проблема? Вы не можете составить запрос к БД с использованием параметров "от" "до"? Или не получается загрузить полученный набор в список комбобокса? Или не можете отловить, когда нужно это всё делать?

Comment: Конкретно не получается загрузить полученный набор в комбобокс.

Comment: Ну например так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24618984/4908529 только там забыли сделать Combo.Items.Clear перед заполнением.